# Optimized/dedicated LAMP-server

Tags: lamp

is there an distro of linux, wich is ready-to-use /optimized
for running apache/mysql/php?

If no, any how-to-set-up-and-optimize blog/document?

Answer (score 1):

Recent Ubuntu versions give an option during installation to have the machine become a 'LAMP server' - Linux/Apache/Mysql/PHP). It can also be done post-install by running 'tasksel', as root (or via "sudo tasksel').

Comment: Ah, perfect! Any idea on how it compares to, for example an debian lamp setup? If there is virtually no difference in speed/performance, should I pick ubuntu?

Comment: Debian is well know for utter stability. Ubuntu is however built on top of Debian though, just a little more up to date. The only significant differences are pretty much versions of software. I'm currently installing Ubuntu 10.4 for all my server deployments.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS is also a great alternative with great hardware support and very nice stability. Pretty much every distribution has a package ready to go for a LAMP based setup during the install process.